# Why my work like this Extrude Faces along Normals

Tags: extrude

Why my work like this Extrude Faces along Normal[image]s

Answer (score 1):

Try these 3 operations before the extrude:

- Select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals
- <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*
- Deselect all and *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces*, or hide some outer faces to check if there are some interior faces, and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Faces Only*